$\lfloor rn \rfloor$ is even for all natural $n$ iff $r$ is an even integer

$r$ is a real number such that $\lfloor rn \rfloor$ is even for all natural $n$ iff $r$ is an even integer.


If $r$ is even, then $\lfloor rn \rfloor$ is ofcourse always even.
But how to prove the other direction? If we prove $r$ is an integer that would be enough. What i tried is say, $r$ is not an even integer, then $2k<r<2k+2$ for integer $k$, then $r=2k+l$ where $0<l<2$, then $$\lfloor rn \rfloor = \lfloor (2k+l)n \rfloor= 2kn+ \lfloor nl \rfloor$$ So, $\lfloor nl \rfloor$ is even for all $n$. Now we probably need to make the cases $l$ being irrational or rational but I'm not sure, help.

Hint: consider the fractional part $r-\lfloor r\rfloor$

We have $0<l<2$.
If $1\le l<2$ then $\lfloor l \rfloor=1$ is not even, so $0< l <1$.
If $\tfrac 12\le l <1$ then $\lfloor 2l\rfloor=1$ is not even, so $0<l<\tfrac12$.
If $\tfrac 14 \le l< \tfrac 12$ then $\lfloor4l\rfloor=1$ is not even, so $0<l <\tfrac 14$.
...
If you continue this process you'll have $0<l<\tfrac 1 {2^n}$ for all $n$ which is a contradiction.

That's very elegant, may I ask what might have been the motivation behind?

You know that  $\lfloor nl \rfloor$ is even for all $n$ so you begin by letting $n=1, 2, 3, 4,\ldots$ and see what happens in those cases.

Here's an alternative solution:
If $1\le l < 2$ then $\lfloor l \rfloor =1 $ is not even, so $0<l<1$.
Now take the smallest positive integer $m$ such that $ml \ge 1$. Such $m$ exists because of the Archimedean property and the well ordering principle. Then, since $m$ is minimal, we have $(m-1)l<1$, which means $ml<l+1<2$. But then $\lfloor ml \rfloor =1$ which is a contradiction.

Wow, this is even more beautiful than your first solution. Exceptional use of extremal principle, can't help but appreciate.
